# Determination of the order of a pole

Tags: complex-analysis, taylor-expansion, singularity

In the function $$f(z) =\frac{sin(\frac{\pi}{2}(z+1))}{(z^2+2z+4)(z+1)^3}$$ the order of the pole in $z=-1$ is correctly two?
Or maybe it is an eliminable singularity?

I have a problem because often if I have an eliminable singularity I only have to Taylor expand the numerator of the fraction at the first term, in this situation, if I expand at the first term I have a singularity of order two and if expand at the second it disappears without becoming zero.

Comment: Yes, it is two. If you take the limit when $\;z\to-1\;$ of the numerator with $\;(z+1)\;$ in the denominator, the limit is finite  , so the remaining exponent in the denominator of $\;z+1\;$ is the order of the pole at $\;z=-1\;$

Comment: All you need to do is to plug the expansions $$\sin u=u\left(1-\frac{u^2}6+o(u^2)\right)$$ and $$\frac1{u^2+3}=\frac13\left(1-\frac13u^2+o(u^2)\right)$$ when $u\to0$, in the fraction and, using the shorthand $w=z+1$, to deduce the correct expansion $$f(z)=\frac{\frac\pi2w}{w^3}\frac13\left(1-\frac{\pi^2w^2}{24}+o(w^2)\right)\left(1-\frac{w^2}3+o(w^3)\right)$$ that is $$f(z)=\frac\pi{6w^2}\left(1-cw^2+o(w^2)\right)=\frac\pi{6w^2}-c\frac\pi6+o(1)$$ for some suitable $c\ne0$, indicating a pole of order $2$ and a residue $0$ at $z=-1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have

$$\frac{\sin\frac\pi2(z+1)}{\left[3+(z+1)^2\right](z+1)^3}=\frac13\cdot\frac1{1+\left(\frac{z+1}{\sqrt3}\right)^2}\cdot\frac1{(z+1)^3}\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n\pi^{2n+1}(z+1)^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}=$$

$$=\frac13\left(1-\left(\frac{z+1}{\sqrt3}\right)^2+\left(\frac{z+1}{\sqrt3}\right)^4-\ldots\right)\frac1{(z+1)^{\color{red}2}}\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n\pi^{2n+1}(z+1)^{\color{red}{2n}}}{(2n+1)!}$$

and we can see clearly in the above Laurent expansion that the pole at $\;z=-1\;$ is of order two. Of course, the above is valid only in some neighbourhood of $\;-1\;$.

Comment: Why is the first equality possible?

Comment: @pter26 That's merely algebra and the Taylor expansion of sine, which is true for **any** value of $\;z\in\Bbb C\;$ .

Comment: Thanks a lot! So can I tell the residue in $z=-1$ is one from this?

Comment: Well, I think it is zero since in the series the first non-constant element goes with $\;(z+1)^2\;$ , so " there is no coefficient of $\;(z+1)^{-1}\;$" , meaning: its coefficient is zero